# run `docker-compose` command with `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Tags: segmentation-fault, docker-compose

I installed `docker-compose` on `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS` followed the docs [Install Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/), but when I run the command `docker-compose`, faced the error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.
And the host machine `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS` is a VM and is created by OpenStack with a 2G memory.
Someone has the same error?

Comment: Could you run `strace docker-compose` and paste the output somewhere?

Comment: I installed `docker-compose` use `pip` and solved the problem, but `docker-machine` also has the problem and `pip` hasn't `docker-machine` package.
This is result of run `strace docker-machine`, [click here](http://i4.tietuku.com/3a54e3edf8bcee1d.png)